# What is the relationship between ScaleTransform and Pixel

Tags: c#, wpf, pixel, transformation, scaletransform

I am new to the concepts of pixels, dpi, resolution and stuffs. So let me put out this simple question for which I am finding hard to get a simple answer

- What is the default measuring unit in wpf
- When I apply a scale transform to a button, how is it getting bigger (whats really happening)
- What is the unit of the zoom factor in wpf
- How is the zoom factor related to pixel (or location of a control that is scaled)

Answer (score 1):

That subjet is quite complex actually.

**Unit**

In WPF, all sizes are expressed in `Device Independent Unit` (*DIU*).

1 *DIU* = 1/96th of an inch.
1 *DIU* = 1 pixel on a 96 DPI display.
1 *DIU* = 2.083333 pixels on a 200 DPI display.

**Scale and Zoom**

You look confused here. A scale/zoom of 1.0 means 100%, 2.0 means 200%, 0.5 means 50%. There is not unit, it's a factor.

Comment: Yeah, I am confused. When I apply a scale transform of 1.0, its the 100% zoom, now when I apply 2.0, you are saying that it zooms the control by 200%. How is the control scaled? Does this increase its Width and Height (no!!), does this relocate the control on the screen  (don't know!!!) - but the control seems to shift away from its initial location as its scaled. How many DIUs has it expanded. Could you give me more information on this, please

Comment: No, Width and Height are left untouched. When the WPF rendering system is about to draw your control, it applies the transformation first, then draw it. So, if you put a 2.0 scale transform on your control, it will appear two times bigger. As for the location, it is controlled by the properties ScaleTransform.CenterX and CenterY. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.centerx.aspx

Comment: So it means that the object is relocated in DIU when it is scaled. How do I easily calculate this location when a control is scaled

Comment: I dont understand why you need to do that... Maybe you should explain what you really wanna do.

Comment: I have a ruler in place. The ruler scale is in cms. A also have a scroll viewer under the ruler. I have a button inside the scroll view and I want the ruler to scale properly when the button is zoomed. Everything works fine, except that I am not able to sync the ruler's scale (scale starts at 0) with the control's start location. Hope you understand the scenario